# javascript, null error when assign to the 'innerHTML' property

Tags: javascript, properties, null, innerhtml

The element variable is not null before assign to the innerHTML property.
it is an array with 5 elements. However it reports the null error after execution.

[image]

Comment: Could you share your HTML code? If possible in a runnable snippet? -- The error basically means the `#title` element cannot be found in the document.

Comment: It is not saying the `element[0]` is null, it is saying that `getElementById('title')` is returning null, hence there is no `innerHTML` property

Comment: See the answers on the linked post. Check if the element with that ID exists on the page when the function is executed.